# How to create autocomplete[real time] text field in iOS, which provides suggestions as you type

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, uitextfield

I'm working on a app. it has texfields.What I want is when user type something in the textfield("**as an exmple think user types letter 'y'**") then below the text field , should show realtime all available names in start from 'y' as dropdown list. then user should be able to select one from it.then the selected items should display in the textfield.how can we do this.

Comment: https://github.com/NeverHopeless/NHAutoCompleteTextField try this

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values . get an idea.

Comment: I want to do this without using third party libraries.

Comment: Then do something like this. Create a array with all your names. When you type something in text-field, at that time, filter the array, create a small table-view same width as text-field, and place it just below text-field., on table did select method, set name as a text-field text.

Comment: Use `UIToolBar` as `inputAccessoryView` of `UITextField`. Monitor changes and put suggestions in toolbar.

Comment: how can I do it, I'm new to ios.if you can please add code.it will help to others also Cy-4AH

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea for auto complete textfield utilising table view.

1. create table view under textfield with hidden property set to Yes.
2. set table view data source based on your unfiltered data.
3. listen to textfield delegate and call function to filter your data source as well as hide/unhide table view based on textfield delegate.
4. set textfield.text based on table view selection.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have another library that makes exactly what you need: https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField

Answer (score 0):

This library should help (both Objc and Swift). As you type it filters results and displays a tableview of suitable results underneath.

https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField

(sorry i couldn't add this as a comment)

Comment: Just seen this has already been answered, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960612/implementing-autocomplete-in-ios